# Using react within C# mvc

Tags: reactjs, razor

I have been asked to implement react within the mvc application we have.

I have created a jsx file called DraftCommentsDisplay.jsx like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

export function test(props) {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, {props.name}!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is bundled into a js file called draftComments.bundle.js through webpack

Now in my cshtml file, I've got the following script sources:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bundles/draftComments.bundle.js"></script>
```

and I'm trying to make reference to the test function in the jsx file by doing:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('my-comments'));
root.render(test("test"));
```

From this I am getting the error: ReferenceError: test is not defined

I thought that maybe I'd then have to import the function and I tried adding:

```
import {test} from "./Scripts/bundles/draftComments.bundle.js";
```

but from this I am getting the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I am trying to do it like this as there will be data from the cshtml file that will be needed to pass into the functions that will be implemented into the jsx file. How can I go about fixing this? I have tried looking online but not seeing anything similar to my issue. I also feel like I might be trying to go about this the wrong way, any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been completely overthinking this issue. You can just simply do something like:

```
const test = "hello";
```

in your cshtml file and then in the jsx file, have something like:

```
function Hello(props) {
   return <div>{ props.title}</div>
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('my-comments'));

const element = <Hello title = {test} />;

root.render(element);
```

and this will work